# Is there a way to use media max width to load a page

Tags: html, css, web

Hope your doing well, I was doing a project a I got into this problem is there anyway to use `<link media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.html">` to load a html project?

Comment: The short answer is no. That is not the purpose of the `<link>` tag. See [link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

Comment: Are you trying to make two different html pages for responsivitiy?

Comment: As I understand it, you want to load completely different html files for different media sizes not just have the same file pick up different CSS depending on media width. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you mean responsive design, you can use media queries as follows in your style.css file:

```
/* Start of your default CSS editing for desktop layouts */
.class-name {
        /* Styling of class for desktop (large) screens */
}
/* End of your default CSS editing for desktop layouts */

/* Here goes media queries for different layouts */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .class-name {
        /* Styling of class for mobiles and tablets */
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .class-name {
        /* Styling of class for medium-sized screens */
   }
}
```

Find more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/height) documentation for media-queries

Comment: But when u already have a lot of css code is there anyway to do it insted of changing every single class

Comment: if you have a lot of CSS code, you would better separate the code in multiple files or even use sass to easily maintain your code. I think there is no other way than that...